# How do I use twitter bootstrap mixins such as .border-radius(10px) in my meteor .less files?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less, meteor

This is my `main.less` file in my meteor app, to which I have already added the `bootstrap` package.

```
@import "variables.less";
@import "mixins.less";

#searchbar {
  .border-radius(10px);
  .box-shadow();
}
```

But opening the app on `http://localhost:3000/`, I get this error:

```
Your app is crashing. Here's the latest log.

Errors prevented startup:
/Users/anup/code/projects/learning/main.less: Less compiler error: .border-radius is undefined
/Users/anup/code/projects/learning/main.less: Less compiler error: .border-radius is undefined
Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

Whereas the `.span4`, `.dropdown`, and all other bootstrap classes work just fine from my `main.html` source (which is also in the base directory, alongwith `main.less`)

How do I use the bootstrap mixins in `main.less`?

UPDATE:
Amazingly, if I put this in `main.less`

```
@import "variables.less";
@import "mixins.less";

#searchbar {
}
```

Then the error changes to

```
Your app is crashing. Here's the latest log.

Errors prevented startup:
/Users/anup/code/projects/learning/main.less: Less compiler error: 'variables.less' wasn't found.

/Users/anup/code/projects/learning/main.less: Less compiler error: 'variables.less' wasn't found.

Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

Comment: Are the bootstrap files in the same folder? If not, you need to provide the relative path, like `bootstrap/variables.less`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Meteor Bootstrap package just contains the compiled CSS code and none of the Less files.  This makes it so you don't need to rely on the Less package to use the Bootstrap package but unfortunately, you don't get all the Less mixins and niceties in your own Less files.  If you want to use those, then you should remove the Bootstrap package, use the Less Meteor package and copy the Bootstrap Less templates, JS files and img files into your app's `public` or `client` folder.

Comment: That sounds alright, and I guess the question is answered. But shouldn't adding the bootstrap package to a project automatically mean that you get to use what the package has to offer. The mixins are a big part of why bootstrap's so compelling. Ideally, simply adding the package to my meteor project should enable me to use its mixins and variables. 
This will do until then.. thanks.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with you, but to play devil's advocate, if you click on the "Download" button on the Bootstrap page, you just get what the Meteor Bootstrap package gives you, i.e. the compiled CSS. Maybe our perspective is different than most users who just want the default styling and aren't going to use much beyond the scaffolding?

Answer (score 6):

There is no `border-radius` mixin in Twitter bootstrap 3. `mixins.less` contains just the following:

```
// Single side border-radius
.border-top-radius(@radius) {
  border-top-right-radius: @radius;
   border-top-left-radius: @radius;
}
.border-right-radius(@radius) {
  border-bottom-right-radius: @radius;
     border-top-right-radius: @radius;
}
.border-bottom-radius(@radius) {
  border-bottom-right-radius: @radius;
   border-bottom-left-radius: @radius;
}
.border-left-radius(@radius) {
  border-bottom-left-radius: @radius;
     border-top-left-radius: @radius;
}
```

Comment: That's is true in Bootstrap 3 but not in 2.x., which is what is included in the meteor package.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved the same issue by using the meterorite project [bootstrap3-less](https://github.com/zeroasterisk/bootstrap3-less/wiki/How-To-Use-Bootstrap3-less-in-Meteor) built for this purpose.